Analog Devices Photodiode Circuit Design Wizard result
Regarding Analog Devices Photodiode Circuit Design Wizard tool, when I need BW of 100Hz with a feedback resistor Rf = 50k, I expect a required feedback capacitor value from the formula:
Cf = 1 / (2πRf*BW)
The above formula gives me Cf = 318000 pF
But the tool sets it to 220pF as shown:

What can be going wrong here?

Don‘t you expect the 5nF capacitor and the input resistor to have a contribution to BW?

The feedback capacitor Cf is there for stability reasons and the tool calculates the value (usually) for a max. flat response (Q = 0.707), depending on the specs of the photodiode ( Ci and Ri ), the feedback resistor Rf and the GBWP of the chosen op-amp.
The pole frequency is fp = 1 / (2 x Pi x Rf x Cf) ~ 14.5kHz. For the chosen OP177 op-amp (GBWP = 600kHz) and assuming Q ~ 0.707, the real 3dB BW of the TIA is f3dB ~ 1.414 x fp ~ 20.5kHz. If you're only looking for 100Hz BW, put an appropriate filter behind the TIA.
